# Using NuGet v3 api with AppVeyor

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core-1.0, appveyor

After we upgraded our web application to asp.net core 1.0 we're unable to get a successfull build within Appveyor.

There are several nuget packages issues, the first error is:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

On of the feed that is used is `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2` and we think it should use the `V3 version` to be able to build core 1.0 web projects.

<s>Is our assumption correct and how do we force appveyor to use the v3 api instead v2?</s>

How do we get a successful build for our asp.net core 1.0 project?

---

**UPDATE**

Our assumption seems not to be correct, with the command

`nuget sources update -Name nuget.org -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

the new v3 feed is successfully used but the build still fails with the same errors.

---

dotnet information from build-server:

***.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-003121)***

***Product Information:***

- Version: 1.0.0-preview2-003121
- Commit SHA-1 hash: **removed**

***Runtime Environment:***

- OS Name:     Windows
- OS Version:  6.3.9600
- OS Platform: Windows
- RID:         win81-x64

And our project.json:

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "type": "default"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
},

"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},

"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {}
},

"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "compile": {
        "exclude": [
            "wwwroot",
            "node_modules"
        ]
    }
},

"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
},

"runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
        "System.GC.Server": true
    }
},

//"publishExclude": [
//    "**.user",
//    "**.vspscc"
//],

"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ]
},

"scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
    }
}
```

And global.json

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try updating nuget source during the build with this command:

```
nuget sources update -Name nuget.org -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Comment: This command works, but the error is sitll the same `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.0.0 is not compatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0` :(

Comment: It would be great to have a repro in a public repository.